# RabbitMQ: How consumer can do not read some messages?

Tags: c#, rabbitmq

How to implement this approach:
I have multiple (3, 10, 100 etc) clients. Each of them is producer and consumer. They generate messages to one the same queue (it is now, can be changed). A consumer should receive messages from all producers excluding its own.
How to do it? How to exclude own messages?

Comment: The most general logic would be to check if the object(or object array) includes an object that has a property similar to `id` is matching any similar `id` property from a single-user's point. If matches, don't act on that or simply remove that from the array or equivalent generic list.

Comment: *They generate messages to one queue* - if you had 3 queues, each client produces to its own particular queue but never consumes it, only the other two queues, you achieve what you want

Comment: Sorry, I mean : messages "to one the same queue"

Comment: @ChristopherH.   Ok, you mean: each client reads  all messages from the queue, then analyzes on the client side  if  parameter contains the client id then ignore else use.

Comment: @ChristopherH write your answer, I'll mark it.

Answer (score 1):

This is a job for a [*topic exchange*](https://jstobigdata.com/rabbitmq/topic-exchange-in-amqp-rabbitmq/) (with associated per-topic queues) - each producer tags each message to the queue with a [*routing key*](https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-four-python.html) which identifies it (the producer) - the routing key can be multi-part of which one part identifies the publisher and other parts identify other useful semantics which you might want to filter on.

Then, each per-topic queue uses a pattern to subscribe to exactly the messages it wants.  And each consumer subscribes to the specific queue that has the the messages it wants.

And: *Only those messages it wants are actually delivered to the consumer*.  It doesn't have to pay for the bandwidth for the messages it is *not* interested in, nor for the CPU to allocate them/filter them out/throw them away.  The server is *designed* to do this and a proper application design takes advantage of that.

(In this particular use case there is one queue per consumer, each queue binding 2 routing keys for the two publishers it wants (i.e., the two *other* publisher/consumers.  In the general case there are other possibilities.)

(The architectural distinction between *exchanges* and *queues* is *absolutely key* to understanding how to effectively use RabbitMQ - and (certain) other message queuing systems too!)

Answer (score 0):

messages are load balanced between consumers.you should not use single queue , you have to use 3 queues to handle your message(read more about exchanges that can route your messages to mutli queue's.).

Comment: But each customer should read messages from all producers, i.e. from all queues excluding it sown. If I'll have 300 users it will be 300 queues

Comment: @ZedZip - queues are fairly cheap - it's not like the _messages_ are copied into each one on the server - also, for some use cases you can use _temporary_ queues (created _on demand_ by the consumer and automatically dropped when he goes away), and for some uses cases you can use _non persistent_ queues.

Comment: Plus, @ZedZip - in your question you talk about --> 3 <-- queues. A specific number because you have a specific number of clients.  3 queues is not too many at all.  Now you're talking about --> 300 <--- queues, a "queue per user".  So now it seems you have an _arbitrary_ number of clients.  Don't you think it would have been a good idea to put this in your question so that we could answer appropriately?  It's not too late: You can _edit_ your question to include this detail as well as others that might be important.